# How to integrate with a function in the limit

Tags: calculus, integration

$\int ^a _0 (\int_0 ^ \sqrt {a^2 - x^2} (a^2 - x^2 - y^2)dy)dx = 303$

I'm trying to solve the above question where the integral has a function as the limit.

Seeing the similarity between the limit and the variable integration, I substituted the $\sqrt {a^2 - x^2}$ with $u$.

Hence I end up with:
$\int ^a _0 (\int_0 ^ u (u^2 - y^2)dy)dx = 303$

After that, I'm not too sure how to proceed as there isn't much to go on as far as integrating $y$ with respect to $u$ is concerned.

EDIT:

Building onto the advice given:

$\int ^a _0 (\int_0 ^u (u^2 - y^2)dy)dx = 303$

$\int ^a _0 [u^2y - \cfrac{y^3}{3}]^u _0 dx = 303$

$\int ^a _0 [u^3 - \cfrac{u^3}{3}] dx = 303$

$[u^3x - \cfrac{u^3x}{3}]^a_0$ = 303

$((a^2 - a^2)^{1.5}a - \cfrac{(a^2 - a^2)^{1.5}a}{3} = 303$

EDIT1:

$\int ^a _0 (\int_0 ^\sqrt{a^2 - x^2} (a^2 - x^2 - y^2)dy)dx = 303$

$\int ^a _0 [a^2y - x^2y - \cfrac{y^3}{3}]^\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}_0 dx = 303$

$\int ^a _0 [a^2\sqrt{a^2 - x^2} - x^2\sqrt{a^2 - x^2} - \cfrac{((a^2 - x^2)^{1.5})}{3}dx = 303$

$\int ^a _0 [(a^2 - x^2)\sqrt{a^2 - x^2} - \cfrac{((a^2 - x^2)^{1.5})}{3}dx = 303$

$\int ^a _0 [(a^2 - x^2)^{1.5} - \cfrac{((a^2 - x^2)^{1.5})}{3}dx = 303$

$\int ^a _0 [\cfrac{2}{3}(a^2 - x^2)^{1.5}dx = 303$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: @moron You can accept/upvote an answer if you think it contains what you wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint.* You do the inner integral first. That is, integrate with respect to $y$ alone, treating $x$ as constant. When you put in the limits, you get an expression that depends on $x$ alone. Then integrate this and substitute the constant limits -- this is the outer integral.

Comment: So I don't substitute $\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}$ with $u$?

Comment: @moron No. It's not necessary. It only serves to declutter things, that's all!

Comment: I added onto my answer, still using u as a substitute before converting it back as I found it confusing. However, I end up with a final equation that is definitely wrong. Is it because of the substitution?

Comment: @moron Your second integration is wrong. Recall that $u$ is a function of $x,$ so you can't treat it as a constant anymore. That luxury ends with the first integral. :)

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, whenever possible, try to *draw a picture* of the region over which you are integrating. In this case, the limits of integration describe a quarter circle in the first quadrant of radius $a$, centered at the origin. This suggests a change of variable to polar coordinates, which turns the integral into

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^a(a^2-r^2)r\,dr\,d\theta={\pi\over2}\int_0^a(a^2-r^2)r\,dr={\pi\over2}a^4\int_0^1(1-u^2)u\,du={\pi\over2}a^4\left({1\over2}-{1\over4}\right)={\pi\over8}a^4$$

Remark: It strikes me as a little odd that the problem would set the integral equal to $303$. I would have expected $32\pi$ instead (for which the solution would simply be $a=4$). But so be it.